# Check if user/role has read/write permission on S3 bucket using AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I am using the AWS SDK for .NET to upload files to S3. If the provided user/role credentials do not have permission to write to the bucket, the upload will fail.

Using the AWS SDK, is there a way to check whether a user/role has write permission to a given S3 bucket *without* attempting to upload a file?

I'd guess that it should be possible to do using the IAM API, but it occurred to me that it would be quite error prone to read in all the policies associated with the user/role and then try to work out how they all interact with respect to allowing/denying a specific action on a specific resource... Ideally I would just use something like the [IAM policy simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html), but that doesn't seem to have a programmatic interface...

Comment: Even services like AWS Load Balancers check if they are given permission to S3 (for log archival) by attempting to write a file to the S3 bucket. That's really the only fool-proof way to do that programmatically.